# clone a job using boto

Tags: boto3, aws-batch

I click on "clone job" button, change an environment variable and submit the second job. Now both the jobs are running without any problem.

[image]

But I have a python list of a few thousand variables those needs to be supplied to this job in a loop. In other words, the job needs to be "cloned" 1000 times. I need to do it using boto for obvious reasons. But what is the best way to clone jobs using boto? The tutorials available on the net shows the entire process of creating job.

Comment: Why you need a clone? Define a job and looping through the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"**containerOverrides**" parameter is the equivalent of "clone job" function of web interface. The submit job method will look like this...

```
client.submit_job(
    jobName=JOB_NAME,
    jobQueue=JOB_QUEUE,
    jobDefinition=JOB_DEFINITION,
    containerOverrides={"environment": [{"name": "senderid", "value": "XXXX"}]},
)
```

The full code will look like this:

```
import boto3
session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id="xxx",
    aws_secret_access_key="xxxx",
    region_name="us-east-1",
)
client = session.client("batch")
JOB_NAME = "nlptensorboto1"
JOB_QUEUE = "arn:aws:batch:us-east-1:302xxx:job-queue/nlpmljob"
JOB_DEFINITION = "arn:aws:batch:us-east-1:302xxx:job-definition/nlptensor:1"

client.submit_job(
    jobName=JOB_NAME,
    jobQueue=JOB_QUEUE,
    jobDefinition=JOB_DEFINITION,
    containerOverrides={"environment": [{"name": "senderid", "value": "xxx"}]},
)
```